# User input not reflected in database (xampp)

Tags: python-3.x, combobox, xampp

In my program, I am getting the user input from combobox and inserting it to database. All values except 'classname' is getting reflected.Its value is shown as zero in the database. I am able to print all the values to be inserted before performing the SQL query.

This the function I executed.

```
def insert_staff():

    id = entry_staffid.get()
    subject = subject_combobox.get()
    class_name = class_combobox.get()
    class_time = timings_combobox.get()

    print(id,subject,class_name,class_time)

    staff = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="school_database")
    cursor_variable = staff.cursor()
    query = "INSERT INTO staff_schedule(staff_id, subject_allotted, class_name, time_allotted) VALUES ('"+id+"','"+subject+"','"+ class_name +"','"+class_time+"')"
    cursor_variable.execute(query)
    staff.commit()
    staff.close()
```

[image: This is how the values are reflected in the database]

Can anyone tell why the value of 'classname' alone is not getting reflected?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you examined `class_name` immediately before inserting the value into the database to make sure it's what you think it should be?

Comment: You should really use parameters to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have printed the value of class_name before inserting it to db and it works fine

Comment: If that's the case, you should probably edit the question to remove tkinter, since tkinter doesn't seem to be involved. Instead, tag it with an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I put the data type of class_name as INT but I was actually using VARCHAR values. This is the reason why the database reflected zero.